# Paypal gives invalid refresh token error and no consent were granted Oauth2

Tags: paypal, oauth-2.0, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to refresh the PayPal access token using the refresh token, I have checked that my credentials are right and I am using sandbox credentials.

Here is my curl request

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic QWNRamY0eHFfOS1JWkpSM3htNURac2hteFhvTFNRb1h3SnZvbFJCM0pfZ0RpcnZpLXFKd21yX2JlYUhRV2gtS2NfRGFOZ19sWXJ1clk3UGw6RUlQVlpRekFqSkZRTmIyTXdsenYtYnRPR2pxejBFUHN5UHpKWF9ObllMSnkydnM3TEFZczBiNGNuUG9ScGZ6RWQ4ZG1manNnelsswrfgth4eGpmTHk=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token' \
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=R23.AAJhMawaln1gQ_bkXioY9SG_Xp5X6CENyIBIcw7F-ocj37o5Io9LN8PKd9EcreWbaQk6LQQuUBXWQmMMaTWokK5eFcD1b0SUjYzS1-YCFLId4vKGmk1q7cELtQc5J477scwsk7cXJEuHwXng-vebMlw'
```

it gives me the response of invalid refresh token and no consent were granted.

```
{"error":"invalid_refresh_token","error_description":"No consent were granted"}
```

access token request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic QWNRamY0eHFfOS1JWkpSM3htNURac2hteFhvTFNRdddb1h3SdsdnZvbFJCM0pfZ0RpcnZpLXFKd21yX2JlYUhRV2gtS2NfRGFOZ19sWXJ1clk3UGw6RUlQVlpRekFqSkZRTmIyTXdsenYtYnRPR2pxejBFUHN5UHpKWF9ObllMSnkydnM3TEFZczBiNGNuUG9ScGZ6RWQ4ZG1manNnelh4eGpmTHk=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'code=C21AAL7QWYekW8pCXkw9xIlsicTcxlytFJfhNCqk3Fvt-WSsjdgpnJF5U5jbP_NB_0xRqOFdSbjdRkcvyDefsoK8Oui6gqj0A'
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Provide more information about exactly how you are obtaining the refresh token

Comment: @PrestonPHX using Oauth2 to get the access token, using the same endpoint and grant_type = "authorization_code"

Comment: And how was the code obtained? Did account logging in consent to anything?

Comment: @PrestonPHX Yes

Comment: I am using test users so there was just login and nothing else was asked to allo.

Comment: What scopes is consent being requested for? Your question should include HTML of the button being used

Comment: `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/connect?scope=openid&client_id=AcQjf4xq_9-IZJR3xm5DZshmxXoLSQoXwfrt565frr43456yhfgdfewwr4JvolRB3J_gDirvi-qJwmr_beaHQWh-Kc_DaNg_lYrurY7Pl&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fboomfront.g66.gopanear.com%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fintegrations%2Fcallback%2Fpaypal&state=eyJkaXNwbGF5TmFtZSI6Ik5FVyBQQVlQQUwifQ%3D%3D` - This is the URL that user is redirected to.    @PrestonPHX